# What is the difference between throw Error and console.error

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two statements, and is there a good reason to use one over the other?

```
throw Error("msg");
console.error("msg");
```

In my limited experience, I've only really seen `throw Error()` used.  Is there any particular reason why?

Also, is there an equivalent to `console.warn()` in the same fashion?

Comment: I think there is a huge difference `console.error` is just used for print the `error` & go on, but `throw` will won't go further .

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`throw ...` raises an exception in the current code block and causes it to exit, or to flow to next `catch` statement if raised in a `try` block.

`console.error` just prints out a red message to the browser developer tools javascript console and does not cause any changes of the execution flow.

Comment: Is it possible to catch console.error logs somehow? I am including an external scripts that I can't influence and unfortunately they are not throwing exceptions but log to console.error.

Answer (score 34):

Some of the Differences are:

**throw Error("msg"):**

1. Stops js execution.
2. Mostly used for code handling purpose.
3. Can alter main flow of execution.
4. This syntax is mostly same for all browser as this is specified and validated by **W3C**.

**console.error("msg"):**

1. It just shows output in Red color at Browser console
2. It is mostly used to print values for debugging purpose.
3. Cannot harm main flow of execution.
4. This Syntax  sometimes vary according to vendor browser and not standardized by **W3C**.

   i.e.  For IE accepted syntax is `window.console.debug("msg")`

Comment: I'm finding more and more that IE loves to be the unique snowflake of browsers.  Does `Window.console.debug()` work with non-IE browsers?

Comment: @Eclecticist -  Mostly all intelligent competitors of IE adapts this as well. so mostly no worries.

Answer (score 3):

Throw is for actually changing the control flow (jumping out of the current context and up to an error handler) for handling errors programmatically. The console statement is just for debugging and printing text to the error console. You may see them used in conjunction, for example:

```
var doSomethingDangerous = function(response) {
   if (isMalformed(response)) {
     throw Error('Response is malformed.');
   }
   process(response);
};

var sendAsyncRequest = function() {
  var request = buildAsyncRequest();
  request.sendThen(function (response) {
     try {
       doSomethingDangerous(response);
     } catch (e) {
       console.error(e);
       doSomeAdditionalErrorHandling();
     }
  });
};
```