# Difference on throw and console.log with promises in catch

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have some trouble understanding why using a `throw` in `.catch` gives me `"Unhandled promise rejection"`. If I simply `console.log` the error everythings works as it should.

> "throw ... raises an exception in the current code block and causes it
>   to exit, or to flow to next catch statement if raised in a try block.
>
> console.error just prints out a red message to the browser developer
>   tools javascript console and does not cause any changes of the
>   execution flow."

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377160/7825826)

It seems like throw is the correct way to handle it? But why do I get an error?

For example (if I don't have any DB running on 1330):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:1330/db')
    .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
});
```

Give me a error message about "Unhandled promise rejection", but if I `console.log(error)`, it's all fine.

Comment: Can you show the code that demonstrates what you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry about that, added my code.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you re-throw `error` in the `catch()`?

Comment: Why do you think that throwing an exception is the correct way to *handle* the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-throw the error in the `catch` callback, the result promise is getting rejected. If that rejection is not handled anywhere (by another `.catch` down the chain), you're getting the "unhandled rejection" message.

This is equivalent to the synchronous

```
try {
    connectToNotExistingDatabase(); // throws exception
} catch(error) {
    throw error;
}
```

which when executing will still throw an exception to its caller. Instead, if you had not re-`throw`n it (but `console.log`ged it) it would just return `undefined`.