# The JavaScript code is not getting executed for other values when it fails for first value

Tags: javascript

There is a loop and the values are passed and based on condition it should execute the script.Please find below the code snippet

```
if (value !== LOCALE || value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
         `value is not set for the tests! Test info`
)}
```

in the above condition if there are multiple values and if the condition fails on first value it throws the error and does not check for other values.I want to execute the test for all the values and if anytime value does not match then it should  show the message and continue the execution.I have tried using return also but still its not executing for other values.
if (value !== LOCALE || value === undefined) {
     return }

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Answer (score 0):

throwing an error always stop the execution of your code. Therefore, you need to do something different. I would suggest that you only use

```
console.error("your message here");
```

to write your error message in the console logs.

EDIT: Found here some more details information: [What is the difference between throw Error and console.error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377115/what-is-the-difference-between-throw-error-and-console-error)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.I had put console.error("your message here"); but instead of stopping the script execution for this case  but its continuing the execution.if (value !== LOCALE || value === undefined) {
     console.error("your message here");
)}.  I want to skip the execution for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

- If you throw Exception or Error control will be out of your code go to jvm. If you want to print value use print() else create a Collection to hold the values and iterate it end of your loop.

```
    List<Error> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Value value: values){
       if (value !== LOCALE || value === undefined) {
          list.add(new Error(`value is not set for the tests! Test info`));
       }
    }
    //iterate list here as per your need.
```

instead use java8 , this will give you your filtered values

```
values.stream().filer(value -> (value !== LOCALE || value === undefined))
```