# Calling function in try/catch block still causes an uncaught exeption [NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, try-catch, discord.js

I'm having an issue with a try/catch block not catching a thrown error from a function called in a try/catch block. The exception remains uncaught even though the function is called inside the try/catch block

```js
const utils = require("../utils.js");
const roster = require("../roster.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'eval',
    description: 'Debug Command',
    execute(client, message, args) {
        if(message.author.id !== client.config.ownerID) return;
        try {
            const code = args.join(" ");
            // let evaled = eval(code);
            let evaled = eval(roster.message('fe', message))
            console.log(code)
            if (typeof evaled !== "string")
                evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);

            message.channel.send(utils.clean(evaled), {code: "xl"}).then();
        } catch (err) { //This is where I expect it to be caught however it remains uncaught
            message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${utils.clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
            return;
        }
    },
};
```

```js
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports.message = function(template, message) {
    fs.readdir("./templates/", (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        template = template + '.js'
        console.log(files + " - " + template)
        let file = files.find(a => a === template)
        console.log(file)
        if(file === undefined) {
            console.log("Err")
            throw new Error("This template has not been found!"); //This is where the program crashes
        } else {
        return file;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the error being thrown?

Comment: The error is being thrown in the second code yes, the function is being used in the first code

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but i think this line is causing it to not throw a error:
`message.channel.send(utils.clean(evaled), {code: "xl"}).then();`, you should probably remove the .then()
However, in the second code provided, i don't know why it would crash when throwing a error...

Comment: hm, weird, does it crash on the eval code or on the template code now? If it still crashes on the template code, maybe change the `Throw new Error("...")` to `console.error("...")` and see if that works. Also, after a bit of research, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377115/what-is-the-difference-between-throw-error-and-console-error/25377266#:~:text=throw%20...,changes%20of%20the%20execution%20flow.), from what i read, `throw` causes the code to come to a halt, but `console.error()` just prints the error in the console.